# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Angular 2/Angular5

Tags: angular

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Angular 2/Angular5

[image]

Error msg:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched:
>   true'.

Current value: `'ng-untouched: false'`.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve tell me.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduction of your problem, otherwise is impossible to help you as we dont know what are you currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this, but here's a simple stackblitz with working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bm9lyn

When using `[(ngModel)]` you don't have to use `(ngModelChange)` event.

Comment: he might be modifying property value , that is reason he is getting error

Answer (score 0):

problem here is you are maing use of `(ngModelChange)`

But if you want to make use of it then code like this

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="result" (ngModelChange)="fnCheck($event)">

fnCheck(event) {
 Promise.resolve(null).then(() => this.anyproperty = event);
 //or 
  setTimeout(() => {
        this.anyproperty = event;
    });
}
```

by making use of promise you will run code after change detection cycle